# Laravel - Automatically Injecting Needed Interfaces When Manually Initializing a Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an API endpoints controller which looks like:

```
class myApiController extends BaseApiController{

    public function __construct(UsersInterface $users, JobsInterface $jobs){

        // Do bootstrap tasks

    }

}
```

The above is only currently being used to provide endpoints for my APIs.  They are referenced in the `routes.php` file in the following fashion.

```
Route::get('api/get',
    ['as' => 'api.get', 'uses' => 'myApiController@methodone']);
Route::post('api/post',
    ['as' => 'api.post', 'uses' => 'myApiController@methodtwo']);
```

Laravel automatically initializes the `myApiController` class above and resolves all the dependency injection in the `__construct()` function.

There's a few functions within `myApiController` which are not bound to endpoints and which I would like to use in another script.  When I initialize the class in this script with:

```
$MyApiController = new myApiController()
```

I get an error stating that the constructor is expecting interface references to be injected.

Is there anyway to automatically inject these interfaces on class initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic Resolution can help you.

```
class FooBar {

    public function __construct(Baz $baz)
    {
        $this->baz = $baz;
    }

}

$fooBar = App::make('FooBar');
```

Please make sure namespace are correct.(for laravel 4 , you don't need namespace)

[read more](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#automatic-resolution)